# Wrapper Class (KnowledgeArticleVersion : KnowledgeArticle) for CaseAssociation Count

Tags: apex, wrapper-class, data-category

I have been trying to build a lightning compoennt that returns a list of article from a single data category and I was wondering how I could go about using a wrapper class to map the returned KAVs to Knowledge Article object in order to sort by CaseAssociationCount. Could someone with better knowledge of wrapper classes give me a hand?

Here is the apex class I am using:

```
public with sharing class GetArticles {

    public String searchTerm {get;set;}

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> getArticlesList(String searchTerm){
        List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = [FIND :searchTerm RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
                                                  (Id, Title, ArticleType 
                                                   WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' 
                                                   AND ArticleType IN ('Troubleshooting__kav', 'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav'))
                                                  WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c AT *DataCategoryName*][0];
        return articles;
    }    


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically and as per books below is the definition of wrapper class

> "A wrapper or container class is a class, a data structure, or an abstract data type which contains different objects or collection of objects as its members."

So speaking from lightning perspective ,you will create a separate class and wrap your knowledge article object with that class .

So lets assume you create a wrapper class as below

```
public with sharing class knowledgeArticleWrapper{
   //Make all your properties Aura Enabled 
  @AuraEnabled 
  public KnowledgeArticleVersion kav {get;set;}
  @AuraEnabled
  public list<CaseArticle> lstcasearticle {get;set;}
  @AuraEnabled
  public integer caseAssociationCount {get;set;}

  public knowledgeArticleWrapper(){
    lstcasearticle  = new list<CaseArticle>();
  }

}
```

You can use this wrapper as a return object in your @Auraenabled method

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<knowledgeArticleWrapper> getArticlesList(String searchTerm){
   List<knowledgeArticleWrapper> articlesWrapper = new List<knowledgeArticleWrapper> ();
    List<KnowledgeArticleVersion> articles = [FIND :searchTerm RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
                                              (Id, Title, ArticleType 
                                               WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' 
                                               AND ArticleType IN ('Troubleshooting__kav', 'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav'))
                                              WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c AT *DataCategoryName*][0];
   //form a wrapper object from your actual objects 
    for(KnowledgeArticleVersion kav :articles ){
        knowledgeArticleWrapper kwrap = new knowledgeArticleWrapper();
        kwrap.kav = kav;
       articlesWrapper.add(kwrap);
    }
    return articlesWrapper;
}
```

Comment: "//form a wrapper object from your actual objects" Do I need to create a virtual object for the results? I think I can set the value in the view without it, right?

Comment: sorry ..just edited so i clarify

Comment: Would these exist as two different apex classes?

Comment: Yes .There is a bug with namespaced orgs in lightning where having inner classes does not provide much flexibility .Better to keep them in separate classes . This repo might be good place https://github.com/CodeScience/seDreamin/blob/master/src/classes/YoutubeDataParser.cls

Comment: So now that the wrapper class is created how would I use the caseAssociationCount to sort my returned data?

Comment: Sorry ..you can put as another question here .You will Use comparable interface to sort..check the same repo that might give you some code